# Localization of Noetherian rings

Tags: abstract-algebra, proof-verification, localization, noetherian

I have this exercise:

> Let $R$ be a Noetherian ring. Let $S\subseteq R$ be a multiplicatively closed set. Prove that $S^{-1}R$ is a Noetherian ring.

First off we claim that given a subset $I\subset R$, $$S^{-1}I \lhd S^{-1}R \quad \Rightarrow \quad I\lhd R\ \land \ I\ \cap S=\emptyset $$ That's true because $$ S^{-1}I \lhd S^{-1}R \quad \Rightarrow \quad (\ \frac {i_k} s \in S^{-1}I \Rightarrow \exists \ d_k\ \mathrm {maximal} :d_k|i_k,d_k\notin S)$$ So if we take the ideal in $S^{-1}R\ $generated by the elements $(\frac {d_1} 1,\frac {d_2} 1,\dots ,\frac {d_k} 1,\dots)$, clearly we obtain $S^{-1}I$, plus $I=(d_1,d_2,\dots,d_k,\dots)\lhd R$. Since every ideal on $R$ is finitely generated, it follows that ideals are finitely generated on $S^{-1}R$ too.

Is this correct? Do I need to be more exhaustive or am I wrong with something? Thank you :)

Comment: When I say that $d_k$ is maximal I mean that there is no $g\in R$ s.t. $g|i_k, g\notin S$ and $d_k|g$, except for $g=d_k$

Comment: Please *do not* ask two completely different questions in a single post. It is better for users to tackle a single, or at most a few highly related problems, rather than distinct ones.  Also, please search for your questions first. In this case *both* are duplicates. Compare your solution to existing ones, and if you think you still dont' know if your approach is valid, post it as a new solution. It will bump the question into view and people will take a look.